# SQlite query order by case

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, sql-order-by

I have a table containing 2 types of text inside a column. The first type is an email address string (ex 222@dsad.com) and the second is a persons name (John Doe)

I am using this query to get the data sorted so that first the rows that don't have the @ char are shown and then the ones that do have it:

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM Name 
ORDER BY CASE 
           WHEN displayName LIKE '%@%' THEN 1 
           ELSE 2 
         END
```

So what I am unable to do is get the cases to be sorted ascending so that I have the names sorted by letter ascending following the emails sorted by letter ascending.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use:

```
  SELECT n.* 
    FROM NAME n
ORDER BY CASE 
           WHEN displayName LIKE '%@%' THEN 1 
           ELSE 2 
         END, n.displayname COLLATE NOCASE
```

The `ORDER BY` clause supports more than one column, but the priority is read left to right.  So the `displayname` values with an "@" in them are at the top, and then ordered by the `displayname` value in that each grouping (based on the CASE statement).

You need to look at using the [COLLATE operator](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#collation) for case insensitive comparison.

Comment: ok this works but not completely. it takes to account if the letter is upercase or not. it gives me the ones starting with upercase letter first sorted alphabetically and then the ones starting with lowercase sorted alphabetically and then it does the same with emails.

Comment: Ok i figured it out. added UPPER(displayName) after end,

Comment: thanks collate worked perfectly. i am assuming is more efficient way to get the same response as UPPER(displayName), right?

Comment: @DArko: Set the column collation appropriately, so neither `COLLATE` or `UPPER`/`LOWER` are necessary in queries.

Comment: Yeah but i am doing this on android and for this i am quering already existing tables which i can't modify so setting this when creating a table is impossible for me so i have to do it in a query.

Comment: +1 Out of curiosity, why alias the only table in the query, and why qualify the column references?

Comment: @pilcrow: In a word: Consistency.  Joins/etc or not, I always use table aliases to explicitly indicate what is coming from the table -- makes it easier to see derived columns.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, it would look like this:

```
Select * 
FROM Name 
Order by case when displayName LIKE '%@%' then 1 else 2 end, displayName
```

You are just adding a second item to be sorted onto the list.  This will sort first by the 1 or 2 column and then it will sort those results by the actual name.

If your collation doesn't allow for the sort you want, you could modify the ORDER BY slightly to accomodate this like so:

```
Select * 
FROM Name 
Order by case when displayName LIKE '%@%' then 1 else 2 end, UPPER(displayName)
```